# Fragment.newInstance() vc onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: android

Why is it recommended (different sources) not to overload the constructor for `Fragment`s but use static `Fragment.newInstance()` with passing a `Bundle` to it?

When you overload a constructor you just explicitly define default one. Than, if your `Fragment` would be recreated for some reason you use `onSaveInstanceState()` with subsequent data extracting on `onCreate()`. The similar situation with using `Fragment.newInstance()`, the only difference you don't need to create public default constructor.

Am I understanding something wrong? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Why is it recommended (different sources) not to overload the constructor for Fragments but use static Fragment.newInstance() with passing a Bundle to it?

Android automatically recreates all non-retained fragments on a configuration change (e.g., screen rotation), and it will use the zero-argument constructor for that. The `Bundle` supplied via `setArguments()` is saved as part of the instance state and given to the newly-recreated fragment. Hence, you only have to implement one method (the factory method) as opposed to three (a non-zero-arguments constructor *and* `onSaveInstanceState()` *and* `onViewStateRestored()`) to take the approach that you suggest.

> Am I understanding something wrong?

If it works for you, go for it. As you note, the factory method approach is a recommendation, not a requirement.

Comment: shouldn't `onRestoreInstanceState()` in your answer actually be `onViewStateRestored()`?

Comment: @ChristopherPickslay: You are absolutely correct. I was probably thinking of the activity `onRestoreInstanceState()` method. I have fixed the answer. Thanks!

Comment: What about an overloaded constructor that calls `setArguments` the same way as your static factory method? Is it just because this is not what people would expect from a constructor?

Comment: @Joffrey: So long as you *also* have the requisite zero-argument public constructor, that's probably fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes of course, always keep the default constructor for the system.

Answer (score 4):

Its better idea not to overload that constructor, because Android can kill your Fragments whenever it needs. And, to recreate them later, it'll call the non-arguments constructor.

To retreive the paramaters, just call getArguments().

```
getArguments().getInt("myInt", 0);
```

The arguments will be available even if your Fragment is recreated.