# Cannot create a default constructor from a class that extends DialogFragment and I have created my own custom constructor

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I'm abit confused on an error message about default constructors.

I have 2classes `MainActivity` and `ResultDialog`. Some methods in `MainActivity` create a new dialog and pass 2strings to a custom constructor in `ResultDialog`.

`ResultDialog` extends `DialogFragment`. So I defined my own constructor but then when that error came up I just created a no arguments constructor and still that is not allowed.

I've searched abit on SO but the answers kind of explain that screen rotation may destroy and recreate the screen using the default constructor but still doesnt answer how I can solve that.

> The error is Avoid non-default constructors in fragments:use a default
>   constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead

Someone please help me on this i'am a bit confused. Part of my `ResultDialog` class:

```
  public class ResultDialog extends DialogFragment {

private String message;//to hold the message to be displayed
private String title;//for alert dialog title

//constructor for the dialog passing along message to be displayed in the alert dialog
public ResultDialog(String message,String title){
    this.message = message;
    this.title = title;

}

public ResultDialog(){
    //default constructor
}
```

Comment: Does the class DialogFragment have default constructor. If not you should explicitly call super(parametes) as the 1st line of you custom ResultDialog constructor. Also if this is not the case please provide the stacktrace.

Comment: I hadnt ran the program yet wanted to sort out the error first but @Raghunandan 's answer worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `newInstance`. Check the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Also check this

[Why do I want to avoid non-default constructors in fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062946/why-do-i-want-to-avoid-non-default-constructors-in-fragments)

```
 ResultDialog rd = ResultDialog.newInstance("message","title");
```

Then

```
  public static ResultDialog newInstance(String message,String title) {
    ResultDialog f = new ResultDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("message", message);
    args.putString("title", title);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

And use `getArguments()` to retrieve values.

```
String message = getArguments().getString("message");
String title = getArguments().getString("title");
```

`getArguments()`

```
public final Bundle getArguments ()

Added in API level 11
Return the arguments supplied when the fragment was instantiated, if any.
```

Comment: worked perfectly thanx alot but for the args I used `args.putString("message",message);` and not putInt.

Comment: @Manny264 edited that part. copy pasted from the doc example. typo error. Some one downvoted

Answer (score 1):

Same works for Dialogs. [Link](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html)
You can not declare your own constructor. Just generate a new instance of your dialog and pass the Strings by Arguments. In your onCreate just fetcjph them with getArguments().getString("key")

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining the separate constructor, you are recommended to only have a parameter-less constructor and use the `setArguments(Bundle)` method to pass data into the `Fragment`. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html):

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the empty constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state restore.

Once you use `setArguments(Bundle)`, you can call `getArguments()` from inside the `Fragment` to retrieve the data.