# Error: Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead [ValidFragment]

Tags: android, android-fragments, apk, release, default-constructor

I have a Fragment named `Fragment_scheduled_newdetail` and following is a constructor I am passing to this Fragment when launching, I get the following error:

> Error:Error: Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead [ValidFragment]

This seems to happen in Android Studio only (I am porting this project from Eclipse, no issue in Eclipse)

When I try to create a app in `release` mode

```
public Fragment_scheduled_newdetail(BlockInfo blockToDisplayT) {
    super();
    this.blockToDisplay = blockToDisplay;
}
```

[image]

If I generate the APK in `debug` mode, it works fine. (`release` mode will fail)
[image]

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062946/why-do-i-want-to-avoid-non-default-constructors-in-fragments

Comment: I would take the suggestion by Android Studio, forget the universal Eclipse (how could they know?). I'll post an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good strong suggestion by Android Studio. The reason is "constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated". Instead setArguments(Bundle) will. This is according to Google webpage @ [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Fragment()).
Do you have code for Bundle passing?

In Android framework, override methods like onCreate and onCreateView are reinstated, not constructors, like when user changes orientation.

Comment: ok, yea trying to figure that out now ... passing bundle between Fragments. Will mark this as answer once i get it working

Comment: @user1406716, I added a comment in my post. It says "In Android framework, override methods like onCreate and onCreateView are reinstated, not constructors, like when user changes orientation"

Comment: @user1406716, How are you doing now with passing Bundles?

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer is already accepted, but for others who finding the most easiest way to avoid this . So just try this, it helps me out :

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

Just write this n your build.gradle file,  then sync the project and try making again signed apk.