# Default constructors in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I don´t have so many experiences with fragments at the moment so i hope anybody can help me with this ! Before the app release compiled fine some month ago and now i have this problem

Android Studio says:
"Problem avoid not default constructors in fragments. "

I hope anybody can help me here to solve this problem.

```
public  static  class TagClickDialog extends DialogFragment {
      private final TagClickDialogListener mListener;
      private final Context mContext;
      private final Tag[] mTags;

      public TagClickDialog(Context context, TagClickDialogListener listener, Tag[] tags) {
            mListener = listener;
            mContext = context;
            mTags = tags;
       }

       @Override
       public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            String[] dialogItems = new String[mTags.length];
            for (int i=0; i<mTags.length; i++) {
                 dialogItems[i] = mTags[i].getValue();
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.tags))
                    .setItems(dialogItems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                       mListener.onTagClick(mTags[which]);
                  }
             });
             return builder.create();
       }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I want to avoid non-default constructors in fragments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062946/why-do-i-want-to-avoid-non-default-constructors-in-fragments)

Comment: You use Intents to send stuff from activity to activity. To send stuff into a fragment use Bundle. Check out Pramod's answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be
>   instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly
>   recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with
>   parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the
>   fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the
>   caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment
>   with getArguments().

Due to this reason we have static factory method when we want an instance of that fragment `newInstance()` in case you want it to have some information instantiated.

[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062946/why-do-i-want-to-avoid-non-default-constructors-in-fragments)

**Update**
you can use following code

```
public  static  class TagClickDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private TagClickDialogListener mListener;
    private Context mContext;
    private Tag[] mTags;

public TagClickDialog() {

}

**update**
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);
mListener = (TagClickDialogListener )context;
}

public static TagClickDialog newInstance(Context context, Tag[] tags) {

    mContext = context;
    mTags = tags;
    return this;
}

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] dialogItems = new String[mTags.length];
        for (int i=0; i<mTags.length; i++) {
            dialogItems[i] = mTags[i].getValue();
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.tags))
            .setItems(dialogItems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    mListener.onTagClick(mTags[which]);
                }
            });
        return builder.create();
    }
}

}
```

this is how you can use it

```
TagClickDialog fragment = TagClickDialog.newInstance("put all the parameters");
fragment.show(fragmentManager, "some tag");
```

Comment: maybe you can give me an example with my piece of of code how i have to change it ?

Comment: Hi thanx but this is not working ..i tried it with an empty constructor too but then it says that this is not initialized : private final TagClickDialogListener mListener;
    private final Context mContext;
    private final Tag[] mTags;

Comment: TagClickDialog.newInstance(mListener, mContext, mTags); is this how you are initializing ?

Comment: No sorry i had to remove the final ..now the code with your changes are working ! But now i have the next problem here :  Error:(107, 40) error: constructor TagClickDialog in class PhotoOverviewFragment.TagClickDialog cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: BaseActivity,PhotoOverviewFragment,Tag[]
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length ....on this code : TagClickDialog d = new TagClickDialog(mActivity,
                            PhotoOverviewFragment.this,
                            allTags.toArray(new Tag[allTags.size()]));

Comment: are you using android studio ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97936/discussion-between-pankaj-nimgade-and-frank).

Comment: yes i´m using android studio. this was not my source code. i just compiled the app some moth ago but now all theses problem occur

Answer (score 0):

From Activity you can send data to Fragment with intent as:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "message is hi");
//set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj=new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and to receive in fragment in Fragments onCreateView method:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // get message from activity        
    String strtext=getArguments().getString("message");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }
```

This is working fine for me. This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a **non-default constructor for a Fragment**, you will be getting this error

```
Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead.
```

Of course this means you have to remove non-default constructors.

***WHAT I USUALLY DO IS***

**1. Use Bundle to pass data** [Unless it's an Object, in which case you have to Serialize it] along with a key, so that in the Fragment, you can get the Bundle via the key

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putLong("key", value);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

Inside the Fragment, you retrieve the argument as

```
getArguments().getType("key");
```

**2. But sometimes I create a setter methods inside Fragment to set the data.**

```
public void setData(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

And when I initialise the Fragment, I call this method right away.

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragment.setData(5);
```