# Display MyFragment to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two java classes. One is `main activity` and other is `MyFragment`. `MyFragment` contains a fragment which has a map. I want to display this to my `MainActivity`. `MainActivity` Consists of  a Navigation Drawer activity. my code for both the classes are:

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_loc) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_set) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_info) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_abt) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}
`

And `MyFragment` Code is:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
GoogleMap mgoogleMap;
MapView mapView;
View view;
public MyFragment(){

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater , ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main,container , false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    if(mapView!=null)
    mapView.onCreate(null);
    mapView.onResume();
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mgoogleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23.2599,77.4126)).title("BHOPAL"));
    CameraPosition bhopal = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(23.2599,77.4126)).zoom(16).bearing(0).build();
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(bhopal));
}
```

}

How can I combine both the classes so that My main activity shows this fragment.
How can I use MyFragment to mainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a member field in your `Activity` like

```
private MyFragment fragment;
```

initialize it in `onCreate()`:

```
fragment = MyFragment();
```

Then attach and show it:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, "your_tag").commit()
```

Where `container` is the id of the layout that should be replaced with your `Fragment`'s content.

**Edit**: it seems to me that you used the Android Studio's "Navigation Drawer Activity" template. The correct layout file would be `content_main.xml` (if you haven't changed that part). You could add your content layout inside the `ConstraintLayout` that was generated by AS:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

*Note that it would be a better approach to use a static factory method for Fragment instantiation, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062946/why-do-i-want-to-avoid-non-default-constructors-in-fragments) for more background.*

Comment: Yes, my Fragment is in content_main.xml .

Comment: Thank you. you made it look very easy.:)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add a container in main_activity.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your MainActivity.java, add this in onCreate (or wherever you want):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, "HELLO");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The first argument passed to `add()` is the `ViewGroup` in which the fragment should be placed, specified by resource ID, and the second parameter is the fragment to add.