# Access to view elements in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which receive data from other activity. This data has to be showed in a TextView in a fragment inflated in the activity. So, the code is:

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

private int idEstablecimiento;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit(); //Here the fragment is added to the activity
    }

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        idEstablecimiento = extras.getInt("idEstablecimiento");
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.nombreView); //Declared in fragmentDetail, which has been already inflated at this point, but still null
    textView.setText(this.idEstablecimiento);   
}

//...
//Non related stuff...
//...

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private int idEstablecimiento;
    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the textView in the onCreate() method is null, why is this happening if the fragment has been already inflated? Shouldn't I be able to access to the IU elements once the fragment has been inflated in the onCreate() method? Or if not, what is the rigth way to do access to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the TextView in the Fragment.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
private int idEstablecimiento;
public PlaceholderFragment() {
}
public PlaceholderFragment(int idEstablecimiento) {
this.idEstablecimiento = idEstablecimiento;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail,
            container, false);
    TextView text = rootView.findViewById(R.id.nombreView);
    text.setText(idEstablecimiento);
    return rootView;
}
```

And then you can get the text and commit it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    idEstablecimiento = extras.getInt("idEstablecimiento");
}

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment(idEstablecimiento)).commit(); 
}
}
```

Regards
Nils

Comment: I think that is not a good idea to overload the constructor in Fragments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602433/fragment-newinstance-vc-onsaveinstancestate/11602478#11602478 but thanks anyway, very useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the View from a fragment layout you should use the view inside the oncreateView of the fragment and then get the textView inside the oncreate view..

example:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail,
            container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.this.findViewById(R.id.nombreView); //Declared in fragmentDetail, which has been already inflated at this point, but still null
textView.setText("I am here");
    return rootView;
}
```