# About Fragment Creation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I want to know why it needs to `putInt` into bundle. When i swipe to other tabs, is my fragment recreated or is the last created used? Why has the blank constructor been used in this?

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0 : return fragment_zg.newInstance(position + 1);
            case 1: return fragment_Uni.newInstance(position+1);
            default: return fragment_zg.newInstance(position + 1);
    }
}
```

And here is my `Fragment`

```
public  class fragment_Uni extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public fragment_Uni() {}

    public static fragment_Uni newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        fragment_Uni uni_fragment = new fragment_Uni();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        uni_fragment.setArguments(args);
        return uni_fragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which argument you are asking for?

Comment: Sorry,    Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        uni_fragment.setArguments(args);

Comment: There is no need to use argument if you don't to. For device orientation change you have to provide one empty/blank constructor to fragment manager. No matter you changed the orientation or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know why it needs to putInt into bundle.

If you want to pass some value to a `Fragment` then you need to use a `Bundle` which is then set as the arguments for the `Fragment`.  Otherwise, the arguments are not retained on `Fragment` recreation.  If your `Fragment` does not require arguments or it is not mandatory then the `Bundle` can be omitted.

> When i swipe to other tabs, my fragment is recreated or used last
>   created?

It will use the last created, but if you want to update then you have to refresh your page adapter otherwise the data will not update.

> Why did blank constructor has been used in this?

It's the default constructor which is required for `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

A `Fragment` always requires a default constructor, but cannot have any other constructors. That's why we use a static method to create an instance and pass the arguments to it.

The reason behind this is for retaining the instance and saving the data as a bundle easily.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602433/fragment-newinstance-vc-onsaveinstancestate/11602478#11602478) for more explanation.

EDIT:
To answer you other question, in this case a new `Fragment` is created every time you swipe. If you would like to retain the fragments you should make the `Fragment` a Singleton.

Answer (score -1):

That is because the way the Fragments are recreated in the Android system. When Android recreates the fragments it reconstruct them using reflection (Java reflection API), so it assumes that the constructor doens't have arguments (because other way it would have no idea how to use it). So why the need of the fragment arguments? The arguments are stored in a Bundle object, which Android knows how to recreates, so that's the reason why it uses a Bundle, Android simply pass the arguments bundle again to your fragments and your fragment use the stored values to recreate himself.

Comment: @Downvoter I would like to know the reason why you downvote my answer. The user asked for the reason about the non argument constructor and the Bundle, so I don't know why the downvote.

Comment: setArgument(bundle) restores my fragment values that existed in last creation??

Comment: Not exactly. When you store data in the fragment arguments bundle, then when Android restore your fragment it'll pass again the arguments bundle, so your last values will be there (for example when you press the home button and Android puts your app in cache). That's because Android knows how to store and restore the Bundle objects, so that's the reason why a Bundle is used.